# pandas merge columns with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`

```
df1
  skuid brand
0  ax12     C
1  zm23     F
2  zm23   NaN
3  zm24   NaN

df2
    sid brand
0  ax11     G
1  ax12     C
2  zm23     F
3  zm23   NaN
```

I need to combine the two dataframes based on the values of `skuid` and `sid`.

```
df1.merge(df2, how='right')
  skuid brand   sid
0  ax12     C  ax12
1  zm23     F  zm23
2  zm23   NaN  zm23
3  zm24   NaN  zm23
4   NaN     G  ax11
```

How can I get the output as shown below?

```
  skuid brand   sid
0  ax12     C  ax12
1  zm23     F  zm23
2  zm23   NaN   NaN
3  zm24   NaN   NaN
4   NaN   NaN  zm23
5   NaN     G  ax11
```

`NaN` value for `sid` on row id 2 and 3,

and one additional row for `zm23` in `df2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you want do this? I think you can't do this in one operation. If you use `right`, you lose `zm24` from df1. if you use left, you will lose `ax11` from df2. So you need to use `outer`, but it won't do what you want. You will have raw `zm23  NaN  zm23` because you merge by `skuid` and `sid`. They are the same at this raw. You can merge your dataframes and then do another manipulation.

And I think you can try use `left_on` and `right_on`, but it won't resolve your problem.

And if you use there, you don't have `sid` in 3 raw.

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['skuid', 'brand'], right_on=['sid', 'brand'])
```

Update: I found the solution. You can fill `NaN`s different values before merging.

```
df1 = df1.fillna(0)
df2 = df2.fillna(1)
df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['skuid', 'brand'], right_on=['sid', 'brand'])
```

If you want you can convert them back.

Comment: this helped, thanks! used `df1['brand'].fillna(0)` & `df2['brand'].fillna(1)` to be specific.